# Unable to delete the SftpFile out of the function C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have written the following function that returns also returns the SftpFile

```
public (DataTable, string, SftpFile) ReadFileFromSftp(List<string> headers ,InboundFileConfiguration configuration, ILogger logger) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (!sftpClient.IsConnected)
                    sftpClient.Connect();
                var fileToBeRead = sftpClient.ListDirectory(configuration.SftpFileUploadPath)
                                             .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(configuration.InterfaceNamePattern))
                                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc).FirstOrDefault();
                if (fileToBeRead == null)
                    logger.LogError(ErrorMessages.NoFilePresentOnTheAzureStorageToRead);
fileToBeRead.Delete();
                using (var remoteFileStream = sftpClient.OpenRead(fileToBeRead.FullName))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        remoteFileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        RemoveArchivedFilesAfterRetentionPeriod(configuration.SftpFileArchivePath, configuration.InterfaceNamePattern, configuration.RetentionPeriod, logger);
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                        return (ReadMemoryStreamContents(memoryStream, configuration.Delimeter, headers, logger), fileToBeRead.Name, fileToBeRead);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sftpClient.IsConnected)
                    sftpClient.Disconnect();
            }
            return (null, null, null);
        }
```

When I write the following code in the function above :

```
fileToBeRead.Delete();
```

It works but when I am deleting the file outside this function it throws the following exception:

`Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession'.`

Please help me

Comment: There's no `.Delete()1` in the code you posted and `fileToBeRead` is a local variable, it can't be used outside the function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't posted because I don't want to delete the file inside the function. `fileToBeRead` cannot is accessed outside function which is clear to me. I just want to delete the SftpFile that the function is returning and that too, outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution & that is :

I created the sftpClient as the static connection.
I am calling one function of that class which is `ReadFileFromSftp` and then I am closing the connection in the `finally` block.
Again, When I call the other method of that same class and try to establish the connection. It throws exception - `Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession'` because the connection has already been disposed in the `finally` block of first method.
I just need not to disconnect the static connection.